The modulus of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ function is also in $H^1_0(\Omega)$
Let $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. I want to prove that $|u| \in H^1_0(\Omega)$. The book I am reading gives a tip: Define $\zeta_\epsilon (t) = (t^2 + \epsilon^2)^{1/2} - \epsilon$ and show that $\zeta_\epsilon \circ u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.
My attemp: Notice that $\zeta_\epsilon \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $\zeta_\epsilon(t) = 0$ if and only if $t = 0$. So, taking a sequence $u_n \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ such that $\|u_n - u \|_{H^1(\Omega)} \to 0$. I think I have to show:

For a fixed $\epsilon > 0$, $\zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n \to \zeta_\epsilon \circ u $, in $H^1(\Omega)$ as $n \to 0$ (which implies $\zeta_\epsilon \circ u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$);
$\zeta_\epsilon \circ u \to |u|$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. So, by a diagonal argument I find a sequence $v_n = \zeta_{\epsilon_n} \circ u_n \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ such that $v_n \to |u|$ in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Is this a right way to go? In this case, how to prove 1) and 2) ?

Lets answer the item 1). Fix $\epsilon > 0$ and  notice that $\zeta_\epsilon'(t) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{(t^2 + \epsilon^2)}}$, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. For each $i=1,...,N$ one has
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}(\zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n - \zeta_\epsilon \circ u)(x)|^2 dx & =  \int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}(\zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n)(x) - \partial_{x_i}(\zeta_\epsilon \circ u)(x)|^2 dx\\
& = \int_{\Omega} |\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u_{n}(x) - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x)|^2 dx \\
& = \int_{\Omega} |\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u_{n}(x) - \zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x) + \zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x) - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x)|^2 dx \\
& \leq 2 \int_{\Omega} |\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u_{n}(x) - \zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x)|^2dx + 2 \int_{\Omega} |\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x) - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x)) \partial_{x_i}u(x)|^2 dx \\
& = 2 \int_{\Omega} |\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x))( \partial_{x_i}u_{n}(x) -  \partial_{x_i}u(x))|^2dx + 2 \int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}u(x)(\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x))  - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x))|^2 dx.
\end{align}
Notice $|\zeta_\epsilon'(t)|^2 \leq 1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$, from which we obtain
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}(\zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n - \zeta_\epsilon \circ u)(x)|^2 dx & \leq 2 \int_{\Omega} | \partial_{x_i}u_{n}(x) -  \partial_{x_i}u(x)|^2dx + 2 \int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}u(x)(\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x))  - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x))|^2 dx.
\end{align}
As $u_n \to u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$ it follows first integral of last inequality goes to zero as $n \to +\infty$. Therefore
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}(\zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n - \zeta_\epsilon \circ u)(x)|^2 dx & \leq o_n(1) +  2 \int_{\Omega} |\partial_{x_i}u(x)(\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x))  - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x))|^2 dx.
\end{align}
Now, as $u_n(x) \to u(x)$ almost everywhere, it follows that $\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x))  - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x)) \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$. Also, as $|\zeta_\epsilon'(u_n(x))  - \zeta_\epsilon'(u(x))| \leq 2$ and $|u_{x_i}|^2 \in L^1(\Omega)$, by Dominated Convergence Theorem the last integral also goes to zero as $n \to +\infty$. Thus
$$\|\nabla(\zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n - \zeta_\epsilon \circ u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \to 0 \text{as } n \to +\infty.$$
Define $v_n : = \zeta_\epsilon \circ u_n$. The sequence $v_n$ is a Cachuy sequence in $L^2(\Omega)$, because
$$
\|v_n - v_m\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C \|\nabla(v_n - v_m)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$
Thus $v_n$ converges to some $v$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, in particular it converges punctually. But, as $u_n \to u$ punctually, one has $v_n \to \zeta_\epsilon \circ u$, punctually  and so $v = \zeta_\epsilon \circ u$ and $\|v_n \to \zeta_\epsilon \circ u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$. Therefore $v_n \in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$, $\|v_n - \zeta_\epsilon \circ u\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$ and $\zeta_\epsilon \circ u \in H^1(\Omega)$, from which we see that $\zeta_\epsilon \circ u \in \overline{C^\infty_0(\Omega)}^{H^1(\Omega)} = H^1_0(\Omega)$.
It remains to prove 2).
